# Hashmap with a boolean or hashset

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

If the value of `hashmap` is a `Boolean` then is it worth using a `Hashset` ? My question would be confusing but its not easy to frame up right words to ask either. The code below explains my problem. The code solves the following question  `Given some cubes, can cubes be arranged such that an input word can be formed from top view of cubes?` eg: assume an imaginary cube with only 3 surfaces where `cube1: {a, b, c}` and `cube2 {m, n, o}`, then word `an` can be formed but word `ap` cannot be formed. I have two approaches for this question, use a `HashMap<String, boolean>` or use a `Hashset`. Advantage of `Hashmap` is that it does not cause a lot of rehashing. advantage of `hashset` is code looks (atleast to me) as smaller and cleaner. What is the right solution / industry wide followed practice in such cases"

OPTION 1:  char[][] m is the set of cubes where rows are cubes and columns are surfaces

```
public static boolean checkWord(char[][] m, String word) {
        final Map<Character, Boolean> charAvailable = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
        char[] chWords = word.toCharArray();

        for (char ch : chWords) {
            charAvailable.put(ch, true);
        }

        return findWordExists(m, charAvailable, 0);
    }

    private static boolean findWordExists (char[][] m, Map<Character, Boolean> charAvailable, int cubeNumber) {

        if (cubeNumber == m.length) {
            Collection<Boolean> booleanValues = charAvailable.values();
            for (boolean available : booleanValues) {
                if (available) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <  m[cubeNumber].length; i++) {
            if (charAvailable.get(m[cubeNumber][i]) == Boolean.TRUE) {
                charAvailable.put(m[cubeNumber][i], false);
                if (findWordExists(m, charAvailable, cubeNumber + 1)) {
                    return true;
                }
                charAvailable.put(m[cubeNumber][i], true);
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

OPTION 2: char[][] m is the set of cubes where rows are cubes and columns are surfaces

```
public static boolean checkWord(char[][] m, String word) {
        final Set<Character> charAvailable = new HashSet<Character>();
        char[] chWords = word.toCharArray();

        for (char ch : chWords) {

            System.out.println(" adding: " + ch);
            charAvailable.add(ch);
        }
        return findWordExists(m, charAvailable, 0);
    }

    private static boolean findWordExists (char[][] m, Set<Character> charAvailable, int cubeNumber) {
        if (cubeNumber == m.length) {
            return charAvailable.isEmpty();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <  m[cubeNumber].length; i++) {
            if (charAvailable.contains(m[cubeNumber][i])) {
                charAvailable.remove(m[cubeNumber][i]);
                if (findWordExists(m, charAvailable, cubeNumber + 1)) {
                    return true;
                }
                charAvailable.add(m[cubeNumber][i]);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HashSet` will be more memory-efficient and time-efficient, but leaves some ambiguity *depending on the application*.

Consider the scenario where a program processes many custom objects of some type `User`, and records their answer to a "yes or no" question.  There are 3 possible states a `User` could be in during this processing:

1. `User` says "yes"
2. `User` says "no"
3. `User` has not been processed yet

Using a `HashSet` alone (i.e. without an additional data structure), depending on the situation it may be ambiguous as to whether or not a `User` not found in the `HashSet` has replied "no", or simply not been processed yet.  A `HashMap`, although being less efficient because it must store multiple `Boolean` instances, would allow you to differentiate between the 3 cases listed above.

Note that in practicality, there are many cases where the 3rd case can be eliminated (e.g. by iterating through every `User` instance so you can assume each processed `User` is only encountered once), and the `HashSet` would be the appropriate choice.

Comment: A HashSet will be no more efficient than a HashMap - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html "This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance)."

Comment: @MichaelT: That is interesting, I didn't know that.  Do you know what `HashSet` maps to for values?  I'm guessing that it maps to `null` instances.

Comment: The [add method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29) stores an `Object` that is a final static for the class (named [PRESENT](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.0PRESENT)).

Answer (score 2):

The solution that uses `Set` will probably be more readable, and easier to maintain - for example you avoid a whole class of problems when you modify your code like "what happens if I put a `false` value in the map - will it break my code?".

As a side note, Java's `HashSet` is quite inefficient memory-wise and actually uses a `HashMap` under the covers. Still, in most cases it is code readability and maintainability that matters most and not implementation details like this.